# IIS Api Controller Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-deployment

I have api controller route like bellow:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "DefaultApi",
               routeTemplate: "api/v1.0/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
           );
```

and I do ajax queries to:

```
'/api/v1.0/MyController/MyMethod'
```

This is works fine when I run my project on localhost, but when I try deploy my project to IIS, I get a "404 not found", because route has been changed to `/mysite/api/v1.0/MyController/MyMethod.`

Question is, how I can run my project correctly on IIS without sitename binding in Ajax query, like: `mysite/api/v1.0/MyController/MyMethod` ? Do I can do this with IIS Rewriter plugin ?

Comment: Show where and how you are using it